# How to pop up the msg box after deleting from cgridview?

Tags: yii

This is the CButtonColumn of my gridview

```
array(
            'header'    => 'Action',
            'class'     => 'CButtonColumn',
            'template'  => '{view} {delete}',
            'buttons'   => array(
                'delete'    =>
                array(
                    'url' => 'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("/workorders/delete",array("id"=>$data->primaryKey))',
                    'label' => 'delete',
                    'options' => array( // this is the 'html' array but we specify the 'ajax' element
                        'confirm' => $alert,
                        'class' => 'grid_action_set1',
                        'ajax' => array(
                            'type' => 'POST',
                            'url' => "js:$(this).attr('href')", // ajax post will use 'url' specified above
                            'success' => 'function(data){
                                if(data == "true"){
                                    //update the grid...
                                    $.fn.yiiGridView.update("workorders-grid");
                                    return false;
                                }else{

                                    $("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'view' => array
                (
                        'label'=>'View workorder detail.',
                        'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/workorders/view", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                ),
            ),

            'htmlOptions' => array('width' => '30px', 'style'=>'text-align:center;')
        ),
```

This is the check the record before delete

```
protected function beforeDelete() 
    {
        if ($this->exists("(status_id = 6 OR status_id = 7) AND parent_mac = '$this->mac_address'"))
            return false;
        else
            return parent::beforeSave(); // prevent actual DELETE query from being run  
    }
```

This is my controller

```
public function actionDelete($id)
    {
            if($this->loadModel($id)->delete())
            {
                if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success','Normal - Deleted Successfully');
                else
                    echo "<div class='flash-success'>Ajax - Deleted Successfully</div>";

                $data = 'true';
            }else{
                if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error','This node is a parents of some other node. <br/>Please replace.');
                else
                    echo "<div class='flash-error'>This node is a parents of some other node. <br/>Please replace.</div>";

                $data = 'false';
            }

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
```

My problem is when the user click the delete button, the confirmation box "Are you sure to delete?" will come out. When user click "Yes", check the record is valid to delete.

If the record is valid to delete, delete the record and "successfully" Msg box pop up. update gridview.

If the record is not valid to delete, "the record is blah blah blah" Msg box pop up.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function actionDelete($id) {
    $jenis = Usaha::model()->findByAttributes(array('id_jenis' => $id));
    if($jenis==''){
    $this->loadModel($id)->delete();
    }
else {
    throw new CHttpException(400, "your message alert "); //try this , will show some alert  this i used when some data connected with another table in database
}

// if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
if (!isset($_GET['ajax']))
    $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));

}
```